# Django DefaultRouter and ViewSets question

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, router

I've this route:

```
router.register(r'posts/(?P<post_id>\d+)/comments', views.CommentViewSet)
```

How do i get post_id in CommentViewSet class?
upd:
views.py

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (MyPremmission,)
    

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(post__id = post_id)
        return queryset


    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I mean i need it in def get_queryset

Comment: Can you share your viewset code?

Comment: @VJMagar check again please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
def get_queryset(self):
    post_id = self.kwargs.get('post_id')
    queryset = self.queryset.filter(post__id = post_id)
    return queryset
```